# Pass Data to Service from Controller AFTER receiving info from Server

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

I need to pass data to an array in service after getting from server. The `controller` runs the function to retrieve data as shown

```
.controller("messagesController", function($scope, $stateParams, RegisterP) {
  // function here retrives data from the RegisterP parameter above calling another service
  $scope.messagepool = [ 1, 2]; //I add the data I get here to an array
})
```

This array then gets sent to a service

```
.service('ChatService', function() {
 return {
   chats: [
     {
       id: "1",
       message: "Chat Message 1"
     }
   ],
   getChats: function() {
     return this.chats;
   },
   getChat: function(chatId) {
     for(i=0;i<this.chats.length;i++){
       if(this.chats[i].id == chatId){
         return this.chats[i];
       }
     }
   }
 }
})
```

That in turn sends that to a view/views. I need to know how to send the info from controller so its the one occupying the `chats: []` so the the views are updated in REAL-TIME. Using the Ionic Framework.
*Bonus:* I haven't researched having the get function in controllers constantly poll the incoming messages however if you can tell me that it'll be helpful and save time.

Comment: Do you want to send $scope.messgaepool data to ChatService ? Is that your requirement ?

Comment: Yes, thats what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

controller

```
.controller("messagesController", function($scope, $stateParams, RegisterP,ChatService) {
 // function here retrives data from the RegisterP parameter above calling another service
   $scope.messagepool = [ 1, 2]; //I add the data I get here to an array
  ChatService.sendData($scope.messagepool);
});
```

service

```
.service('ChatService', function() {
   return {
     sendData:function(data){
         this.chatData=data;
         console.log(this.chatData);
         //  this.getChats(); you can call service function from here
        },
     getChats: function() {
        console.log(this.chatData); // it will work here too
        return this.chats;
       },
     getChat: function(chatId) {
        for(i=0;i<this.chats.length;i++){
        if(this.chats[i].id == chatId){
        return this.chats[i];
        }
      }
     }
    }
 });
```

Hope it will help you :) Thanks